# Contact details bar should collapse vertically when open in mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

This is my html code:

```
<div class="topbarsection">
   <ul>
     <li class="alignleft">
       <a href="#">Office Address</a>
     </li>
     <li class="aligncenter">
       Office Timings
     </li>
     <li class="alignright">
       <a href="tel:0123456789">0123456789</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
.topbarsection {
background-color: #002e5b;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
color: #fff;
display: block;
font-family: Open Sans,arial;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 10px 5px;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 10000;
}
.topbarsection a {
color: #fff;
}
ul li {
display:inline;
list-style-type:none;
}
.alignleft {
float: left;
width:33.33333%;
text-align:left;
}
.aligncenter {
float: left;
width:33.33333%;
text-align:center;
}
.alignright {
float: left;
width:33.33333%;
text-align:right;
}
```

In browser on Desktop, I'm getting this result, check screenshot 1:

[image]

In browser on Mobile, I'm getting this result, check screenshot 2:

[image]

First problem is, on Desktop browsers, Mobile number is hiding, check screeshot1.

Second problem is, on Mobile browsers, all three details is showing in one line. But I want this List on contacts in vertical, like this, check screeshot 3:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with your code.

1. To fix for mobile an option is to use media queries.
2. If you must float, use clearfix to prevent any collapsing of the parent
3. Take out your default margin/padding on your ul
4. you don't need z-index on the parent
5. change the width of li to 100% at the smallest size, and display:block; this will stack.
6. Add a viewport metatag for mobile. search on wc3
7. please be more detailed in your posts. !

here is your updated code --  I have only fixed for under 480px, please add your own queries using my example to improve responsive layout.

Let me know if this helps!!!!!!!!!

```
<div class="topbarsection clearfix">
   <ul>
     <li class="alignleft">
       <a href="#">Office Address</a>
     </li>
     <li class="aligncenter">
       Office Timings
     </li>
     <li class="alignright">
       <a href="tel:0123456789">0123456789</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
.clearfix:after {visibility: hidden; display: block; font-size: 0; content: " "; clear: both; height: 0; }

.topbarsection {
background-color: #002e5b;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
color: #fff;
display: block;
font-family: Open Sans,arial;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 10px 5px;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
.topbarsection a {
color: #fff;
}
ul{
  margin-right:2%;
  padding:0;
}

ul li {
display:inline;
list-style-type:none;
}
.alignleft {
float: left;
width:33.33333%;
text-align:left;
}
.aligncenter {
float: left;
width:33.33333%;
text-align:center;
}
.alignright {
float: left;
width:33.33333%;
text-align:right;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  ul li{
    display: block;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0;
  }
  .alignleft,
  .aligncenter,
  .alignright{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ranjeet, try this.

Add this to your head section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Then replace your css like this:

```
.topbarsection {
background-color: #002e5b;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
color: #fff;
display: block;
font-family: Open Sans,arial;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 10px 5px;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 10000;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
.topbarsection a {
color: #fff;
}
ul li {
display:inline;
list-style-type:none;
}
.alignleft {
float: left;
width:33.33333%;
text-align:left;
}
.aligncenter {
float: left;
width:33.33333%;
text-align:center;
}
.alignright {
float: left;
width:33.33333%;
text-align:right;
}
}
```

And look into media queries!

Answer (score 0):

The first issue you can solve by putting an additional wrapper div inside the `.topbarsection` div. It is the `padding` that is causing your content to not line up properly because the div being set to `width: 100%` does not account for the padding so it is added to the overall width.

To solve this, don't use any padding on the `.topbarsection` div, add a second `.wrapper` div with the appropriate padding, and then put your content inside of it.

The second issue you can solve using a `@media` query. Look it up and you will see that you can have an alternate CSS layout for your `<li>` elements once the screen reaches a certain width.